# How do I make a bash script know the output of a CLI program it executed in Linux?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

If I create a script that executes a CLI program then the output is shown directly in the terminal. How do I make the bash script aware of what the executed program is outputting in the terminal?

For example if the script executes a program that outputs a particular sentence or number. How do I make the bash script know the sentence or number or any other data that is outputted.

Comment: Is this really what you want? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
OUTPUT=$(command here)
```

or

```
OUTPUT=`command here`
```

E.g.:

```
NUM=`echo 4`
if [ $NUM -eq 4 ] ; then echo OK ; fi
```

Comment: Note that the advantage of using `$(...)` over `\`...\`` is that command substitutions can be *nested*; e.g.: `OUTPUT=$(echo "The OS is: $(uname)")`. Also, I suggest you use `[[...]]` for the test in your example - in the bash world, it's the superior alternative to `[...]`.

Comment: Adding on @mklement0's, `\`...\`` is deprecated

Comment: What happens if the program gives multi-line output? Are all lines added to "OUTPUT"?

Comment: Then you need to wrap the output in quotes: `NUMS="$(echo -e '4\n5')"`, then you can iterate over the lines like this: `for line in $NUMS ; do ... done`

Comment: The advantage of using `\`...\`` is that you do not need to escape it when passing it in an argument on the command line.